# Add page title, img2pdf

Tags: python, bash, image, pdf, file-conversion

I've recently found this (wonderful) python software to convert multiple images to a single pdf, [img2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/). After create the first pdf I realized that every page hasn't got any title and it's difficult identify what's the original image (because there're 400), does anyone know how can I add a page title?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the software, or how to use img2pdf as a library?

Comment: No, I know how to use it and the output I get is correct... my question is about how to add a title with the filename of each image in every page of the generated PDF. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but are you using img2pdf as a standalone program, or are you accessing the library from your own python script?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't understand you. I'm using img2pdf as a standalone program.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find the same solution but ended up writing a Python program to solve it. I dont know if it helps you but here is a solution nonetheless.

In Python I used PIL.Image and ImageDraw to go through all images and put the filename in each if the images. After that I used img2pdf as a python library to generate the pdf.

Must be run it in the same folder of the images.

```
import os
import img2pdf
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ExifTags

# Enter the path to the font you want, 'fc-list' on ubuntu will get a list of fonts you can use.
#image_text_font = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 15)
image_text_font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf", 32)

# Tags the images with 'file name' in the upper left corner
def tag_images():
    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if file.endswith(".jpg") and str(file+"_tagged.jpg") not in os.listdir('.') and not file.endswith("_tagged.jpg"):
            one_image = check_and_adjust_rotation(Image.open(file))
            one_image_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(one_image)

            # Add textbox to image
            size = one_image_draw.textsize(file, font=image_text_font)
            offset = image_text_font.getoffset(file)
            one_image_draw.rectangle((10, 10, 10 + size[0] + offset[0], 10 + size[1] + offset[1]), fill='white', outline='black')

            # Add text to image
            one_image_draw.text((10,10), file, font=image_text_font, fill='black')

            # Save tagged image
            one_image.save(file + "_tagged.jpg")
            print(f'Tagged and saved "{file}_tagged.jpg".')

# Generate the PDF
def generate_pdf_from_multiple_images():
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img2pdf.convert([image_file for image_file in os.listdir('.') if image_file.endswith("_tagged.jpg")]))

# Use exif information about rotation to apply proper rotation to the image
def check_and_adjust_rotation(image):
    try :
        for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys() : 
            if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation' : break 
        exif=dict(image._getexif().items())
        print(exif[orientation])

        if   exif[orientation] == 3 : 
            image=image.rotate(180, expand=True)
        elif exif[orientation] == 6 : 
            image=image.rotate(270, expand=True)
        elif exif[orientation] == 8 : 
            image=image.rotate(90, expand=True)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

    return image

def main():
    tag_images()
    generate_pdf_from_multiple_images()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```